# why facelet html validator in eclipse is taking endless time

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, facelets, eclipse-luna

I am using Eclipse Luna to implement JSF2.1 web application, and each time i open the project the facelet HTML validator starts, I am used to eclipse Helios and it was faster than luna in validation, I don't want to disable the validator or AppXray. I just don't wanna suffer from it

Please advice

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm using Kepler and AppXray Resource Change Handler is doing the same thing.

Comment: The Facelet HTML Validator is just a piece of crap in Eclipse. Takes almost 10s to validate a page.

Comment: After Luna came Mars, Neon and now Oxygen(2). Still got that problem since it seems to be working fine the last couple of years